# Hibernate error column0_.id does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a model class that is mapped to a postgres database using hibernate. My model class is:

**CheckRes.java**

```
package com.example.demo.model;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="checkers",schema = "public")
public class CheckRes {
    public long getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(long ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getCheck() {
        return check;
    }

    public CheckRes() {
    }

    public void setCheck(String check) {
        this.check = check;
    }

    @Id
    private long ID;

    public CheckRes(String check) {
        this.check = check;
    }

    @Column(name="check")
    private String check;

}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

The following table is already existing in db with create script as:

```
CREATE TABLE public."checkers"
(
    "ID" bigint NOT NULL,
    "check" character varying(20),
    CONSTRAINT "checkers_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public."checkers"
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Later when I am trying to invoke the controller get method from a postman , I am getting the following error.

> **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column checkres0_.id does not exist
> Position: 8**

If the table doesnt exist then hibernate automatically creates a table with '_' and there are no errors. But I dont need the hibernate to create any tables. It just needs to use the existing ones for CRUD operations,is there any other naming convention I am missing?

Comment: You should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names - I wouldn't be surprised if that also solves your problem at hand

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Can you please provide your comments as answer , so that I can accept it . Basically changing the column name from "ID" to "id" worked for me

Comment: Actually, don't use double quotation(`""`) when creating column then it became case sensitive use like `ID bigint NOT NULL` then it by default became `id`. Still, if you want to use `"ID"` then in JPA you should map using `@Column("\"ID\"")` with quote, since hibernate don't use quote by default, so it became `id` when query.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this is a good practice to follow [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html). According to that you should rename `ID` field to `id`.

And then as was noticed by @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks and @a_horse_with_no_name you should use `@Column` with [quotes](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-quoted-identifiers):

```
@Id
@Column(name="`ID`")
private long id;
```

Also your [getters and setters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-pojo-accessors) should follow *JavaBean conventions*. So, for the above field you should have the following getter and setter:

```java
public long getId() {
   return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
   this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: May be quotes also needed

Comment: @SternK: but `"ID"` is a different [column name](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) than `id` (or `ID`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you were right! I have corrected the answer.

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks It works! I tested that. Actually, when hibernate issued  query it contents ""